# how to go through all possible combinations for filling an array or set of variables

Tags: c#

This kind of questions may have been already answered, but I can't go past the process of conception for a small programm I am trying to make in C#.

What I want to do is :

-I have n = 100

-I also have 9 variables/an array of 9

-I want to get all the possible combinations of distributing n between all 9 variables, like :

```
v1 = 100;
v2 = 0;
v3 = 0;
v4 = 0;
v5 = 0;
v6 = 0;
v7 = 0;
v8 = 0;
v9 = 0;
```

or

```
v1 = 10;
v2 = 5;
v3 = 13;
v4 = 27;
v5 = 0;
v6 = 34;
v7 = 0;
v8 = 11;
v9 = 0;
```

I have looked at the heap's algorythm, but it does not seem to fit, or I may not understand the full concept.

Also, what is the method to calculate the number of combinations, is the product method the right one ?

EDIT : I found the number of possible combinations using an online tool that found a continuation. The total of these is "352 025 629 371". yeah it will take a while to go through all of these.

Comment: So you want every combination of 9 numbers that add to 100? Are negative numbers permitted?

Comment: yes that's it, and it's only for positive numbers and 0, that's actually way clearer when said that way

Comment: If `100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0` is one combination, is `0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,100` another? Or do you want them to be treated as just one combination (since they are the same but in a different order)?

Comment: they are to be treated as separate combinations, because these variables will influence different calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may get you started. It just brute forces all of the combinations.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Bob
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static IEnumerable<Combination> GetData()
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < 101; a++)
            {
                for (int b = 0; b < 101; b++)
                {
                    for (int c = 0; c < 101; c++)
                    {
                        for (int d = 0; d < 101; d++)
                        {
                            for (int e = 0; e < 101; e++)
                            {
                                for (int f = 0; f < 101; f++)
                                {
                                    for (int g = 0; g < 101; g++)
                                    {
                                        for (int h = 0; h < 101; h++)
                                        {
                                            for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
                                            {
                                                var sum = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i;

                                                if (sum == 100)
                                                {
                                                    yield return new Combination(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i);
                                                }
                                                else if (sum > 100)
                                                {
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sampleResults = GetData().Take(200); // this will show 200 (remove .Take(100) to show them all)

            foreach (var result in sampleResults)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Combination
    {
        public readonly int V1;
        public readonly int V2;
        public readonly int V3;
        public readonly int V4;
        public readonly int V5;
        public readonly int V6;
        public readonly int V7;
        public readonly int V8;
        public readonly int V9;

        public Combination(int v1, int v2, int v3, int v4, int v5, int v6, int v7, int v8, int v9)
        {
            V1 = v1;
            V2 = v2;
            V3 = v3;
            V4 = v4;
            V5 = v5;
            V6 = v6;
            V7 = v7;
            V8 = v8;
            V9 = v9;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7} {8}", V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6, V7, V8, V9);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually did not thought of doing the brute force that way, I was thinking in the wrong way. This will take a while to go through all combinations, but at least it will. I will start to build my code around it then, thank a whole lot.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to mjwills solution is to use a recursive method that brute forces.

An optimization is to not run through everything, but to limit the search to numbers only up to 100 - the current sum (since if the current sum is, say, 50, we know that the next number can't possibly be > 50 since that would sum to more than 100.).

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sampleResult2 = BruteForceCombinations(new List<int>(), new List<Combination>());

        foreach (var result in sampleResult2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Combination> BruteForceCombinations(List<int> listSoFar = null, List<Combination> validCombinations = null)
    {
        if (listSoFar.Count == 9)
        {
            if (listSoFar.Sum() == 100)
            {
                List<int> validCombinationList = new List<int>();
                validCombinationList.AddRange(listSoFar);

                validCombinations.Add(new Combination(validCombinationList));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Run from 0 to 100 - the sum of list entries so far + 1, as any number larger than that will create a sum larger than 100
            for (int i = 0; i < 100 - listSoFar.Sum() + 1; i++)
            {
                // Add the number to test the combination and remove after
                // The combination is added if we hit one that sums to 100.
                listSoFar.Add(i);
                BruteForceCombinations(listSoFar, validCombinations);
                listSoFar.RemoveAt(listSoFar.Count-1);
            }
        }

        return validCombinations;
    }
}

public class Combination
{
    private readonly List<int> numbers; 

    public Combination(List<int> numbers)
    {
        this.numbers = numbers;
    } 

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(";", this.numbers);
    }
}
```

I haven't had a chance to run through the complete program, but I think it will yield the correct result. At least, the idea of recursion is shown.

Comment: I just found there are "352 025 629 371" possible combinations, it would take a lot of time to go through it completely ^^

Comment: If you did use this solution, you would definitely want to switch it to use `yield return` since `validCombinations` won't fit in RAM.

Answer (score -1):

I would check Backtracking algorithms if I were you. It actually constructs what you need, but as I know it is memory-consuming.

As about the number of combinations there is the formula: 
Combinations of 100 taken in groups of 10 equals: 100!/[10!*(100-10)!]